# Java + Spring Boot: I am trying to add CacheControl header to ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I am not so good in Java + Spring, but I'd like to add `Cache-Control` header to my `ResponseEntity`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/data/{id}", method = GET")
public ResponseEntity<String> getData(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    try {
            ...
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setCacheControl("max-age=600");

            return new ResponseEntity<String>(body, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
}
```

I added two lines of code for `HttpHeaders` and now I get two `Cache-Control` headers in my response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Cache-Control: max-age=600
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 18223
Date: Wed, 29 Jun 2016 21:56:57 GMT
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you using Spring Security?

Comment: Yes, my app has basic authentication for reaching REST API.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## TL;DR

---

Just add the following to your `application.properties`:

```
security.headers.cache=false
```

## More Details

---

As [Spring Security documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#default-security-headers) states:

> Spring Security allows users to easily inject the default security
>   headers to assist in protecting their application. The default for
>   Spring Security is to include the following headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

> now I get 2 CacheControl headers in my response

One of them is provided by Spring Security. If you don't like them, you can disable the default `Cache-Control` headers in your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // Other configurations

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                // Other configurations
                .headers()
                    .cacheControl().disable();
    }
}
```

Since you're using Spring Boot, you can achieve the same using the `security.headers.*` properties. In order to disable that default `Cache-Control` header, just add the following to your `application.properties`:

```
security.headers.cache=false
```

Also, more idiomatic way of adding `Cache-Control` headers is to use the new `cacheControl` builder:

```
ResponseEntity.ok()
              .cacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
              .body(body);
```

Comment: great, this worked for me too. For some reason the `security.headers.cache=false` thing did not affect the results, however explicitly extending the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` did the trick. Now I have my controllers explicitly declaring their caching policy. Great hint.